# Body not correct for MySQL INSERT for POST Method

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, postman

All my methods like SELECT, etc are OK, I can retrieve my data in Postman.

But, my method INSERT INTO to add data in my database does not work in Postman. The body seems to be not correct.

This is the body I tried to send with Postman :

```
{
    "id": 2000,
    "code": 4,
    "alpha2": "AF",
    "alpha3": "AFG",
    "name_en": "Afghanistan",
    "name_fr": "Afghanistan"
}
```

Here is the code in node.js :

```
app.post('/country', function (req, res) {

    let country = req.body.country;

    if (!country) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide country' });
    }

    mc.query("INSERT INTO country SET ? ", { country: country }, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'New country has been created successfully.' });
    });
});
```

Here is the response I got in Postman :

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Please provide country"
}
```

Here is my SQL Database :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using body-parser package and have correctly loaded it,

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser);
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

then, your payload is not correct.

You need to have the `country` key in the root of the object -

```
{
 "country": {
    "id": 2000,
    "code": 4,
    "alpha2": "AF",
    "alpha3": "AFG",
    "name_en": "Afghanistan",
    "name_fr": "Afghanistan"
 }
}
```

Your current code is looking for `req.body.country` when it does not exist. If you'll execute `req.body.alpha3` you'll see what I mean.

-- 
Edit:

Your SQL also has issues.

1. Insert statment should be `INSERT into Country VALUES(?,?,?), [...parameters]
2. You shouldn't be using the SET keyword in the Insert statement.

--

Edit 2:

Based on the mysql package documentations, you should construct the query as follows -

```
mc.query("INSERT INTO country SET ? ", country, function (error, results, fields) {....
```

Don't wrap country inside another object assuming you create the object as I described before with country present in the root. Otherwise, just pass the req.body as it is (of course, you should be escaping the queries).

Comment: Yes I already tried of course. Then I got an error in console : "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR" : Field 'country' unknown in field list.

Comment: Your SQL also has issues. You need to update your question with the table details if we can help any further. Also see updated answer.

Comment: It works, but how should I construct my query if I would like to not precise the key country into my root?

Comment: Just pass req.body as it is. Your existing keys should match the table columns. And also do validate and escape the body before executing the query

Comment: Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

`let country = req.body.country;`
you are looking for a value of 'country' in you req.body which you don't have.

try adding it to the body

```
{
   "id": 2000,
   "code": 4,
   "alpha2": "AF",
   "alpha3": "AFG",
   "name_en": "Afghanistan",
   "name_fr": "Afghanistan"
   "country": "sample country"
}
```